# Can I compile my R package in bytecode?

Tags: r, package

Can I compile my R package in bytecode? I have an R package and I want to compile it with

```
R CMD INSTALL --build mypackage.tar.gz
```

but I want the R code to be compiled into bytecode. Is this possible in R 2.14.0?

Comment: I'm sure there is a good reason, but it eludes me at the moment, so why do you want to byte-compile your package ?

Comment: @PaulHurleyuk Because there is a reasonable chance that in doing so the package will gain a small to moderate speed-up. For free.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is listed in the NEWS for R 2.14 and in the R extensions manual.

NEWS:

> R CMD INSTALL has a new option --byte-compile to byte-compile the
>         packages during installation (since all packages are now
>         lazy-loaded).  This can be controlled on a per-package basis by
>         the optional field ByteCompile in the DESCRIPTION file.

The ByteCompile field is described in section 1.1.1 of the "Writing R Extensions" manual for the DESCRIPTION file.

The manuals on CRAN are still 2.13.2 so I looked in the installed version of the extensions manual for that.

Comment: Thanks mdsummer, now I am looking for how to actually use 'ByteCompile' because "Writing R Extensions" only describes the existence of the field. I have submitted a question to r-devel.

Comment: waiting for r-devel approval, so posted it here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978910/how-do-i-use-the-new-bytecompile-field-in-r-2-14

Comment: In the DESCRIPTION file, you can specify the line `ByteCompile: true`.
On an ad-hoc basis, you can use `R CMD INSTALL --byte-compile` or `install.packages("pkgName", type="source", INSTALL_opts="--byte-compile")`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343174/r-2-14-byte-compile-not-possible-with-install-packages.