# How do I use the new 'ByteCompile' field in R-2.14?

Tags: r, package

I would like to the use the 'ByteCompile' field in R 2.14. However,
"Writing R Extensions" only describes this field, but does not say
what value it should be set to. How should i use it? Do you have
examples?

Is it the same as "LazyData: yes"?

I also asked [this question](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-November/062409.html) on the r-devel mailinglist.

Comment: Please don't crosspost between SO and the mailing lists for R without clearly stating so. There are enough people on both SO and the mailing list, and they don't like to answer the same question twice...

Comment: @JorisMeys, okay I'll remember for next time, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a boolean value. Set it to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If you do not specify it in the DESCRIPTION file then it defaults to `FALSE`. For convenience you could alternatively use `yes` or `no` for these boolean fields.

Note that I too could find no documentation for this, or perhaps did not know how to interpret the documentation. I worked it out from the [source](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/tools/R/install.R).