# R 2.14 byte compile - not possible with install.packages?

Tags: r

It seems that R 2.14 can byte-compile packages using a switch on `R CMD INSTALL` but I couldn't find such an option in the install.packages documentation.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it says in `?install.packages`, you can use the `INSTALL_opts=` argument to pass additional options to `R CMD INSTALL` for a source package install.  If you're installing a binary package from CRAN, it's likely already byte-compiled.

For example, to install from source and byte-compile manually (make sure you have the [necessary tools](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Installing-packages)):

```
install.packages("xts", type="source", INSTALL_opts="--byte-compile")
```

Comment: so install.packages( PACKAGE_NAME , INSTALL_opts = "--byte-compile" ) will download the package from CRAn and install it byte-compiled?  How do I tell if a package is byte-compiled?

Comment: That will only work if you're installing from source.  I'm not sure how to tell if a package is byte-compiled, other than printing a function from the package.  E.g. `base:::as.matrix` will include `<bytecode: 0x...>` near the end of the printed output.

Comment: I'll post separately on the question of how to tell if a package is byte-compiled.  Updating my post to show the statement required to download package, byte-compile, and install using install.packages. thanks for your help!

Comment: @SFun28: let me just add that to my answer.  Solutions in questions make me sad.